# Emulate vanila Android-arm64 on PC

Tags: vanilla-android, aosp, arm-processors

I need to examine how the ELF binary (which is compiled for ARM processor) executes on Android-arm64. Can you please suggest how I can emulate Android-arm64 on the x86 system?

I have checked Android studio, but it seems that it only runs a single application but not the whole Android system.

Comment: Test in an Android Emulator or on a physical device.

Comment: Android Studio includes SDK manager and and AVD manager which you can use to install and run a virtual Android device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have checked Android studio, but it seems that it only runs a single application but not the whole Android system.

You are mistaken. The Android emulator in Android Studio creates and runs an entire virtual Android device. It's set up to make it particularly easy to do this with an app that you're developing in Android Studio, but that is not all of what it can do.